# Edit SSRS report on SharePoint

Tags: reporting-services, sharepoint-2010, edit

There is an SSRS report embedded into SharePoint that needs to be fixed (the report does). I am familiar with SSRS and SharePoint, but not with the two together. Usually when I work with SSRS it is in Visual Studio. I can fix reports from there, and deploy them to the report server. But I'm not sure how the report got to SharePoint. Someone else put it there and now they are gone and I need to fix it. How do I go about editing / fixing an SSRS report on a SharePoint site? Where is this report anyways, on the report server with a link to it? I cannot find it there.

Please help.

Comment: How is the report showing in SharePoint? Is it running in a webpart? The webpart could simply be showing the report and the report is on your normal report server. Alternatively, is SSRS running in SharePoint integration mode on this server?

Comment: There are several ways that your report could be in there. I deploy to **SharePoint** with a **TargetReportFolder** of `http://sharepointreports/sites/ExternalDataReports/Reports/AllDepartments/XYZ Reports/Health Services`. If your report list looks like http://imgur.com/oeCydgc, click on **Site Contents** to find the reports in a folder like Documents, Pages, or Dashboards. If not, post a pic of your site with your report link.

Answer (score 0):

Once in Sharepoint, click the dropdown arrow next to the report as shown below and choose 'Edit in Report Builder'.

[image]

Report Builder will take a few minutes to open.  Once Report Builder is open, then you can edit the report and save it.  Refresh the SharePoint site and your report will be updated.

Depending on your version of SSMS.  I have SSMS 2008R2, which is compatible with Report Builder 3.0
Here's the link to download Report Builder 3.0
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=6116

I had the same struggle once.  Hope this helps.

Comment: I doesn't work properly for me. When I click on "Edit in Report Builder", for some reason it makes me download "ReportBuilder_3_0_0_0.application", instead of opening the report. Yesterday, for unknouwn reasons (stars must've aligned lol), it opened Report Builder 2008 R2 properly with the report. However, today, it does this. FYI I have Report Builder 2016 installed locally not the 2008. So where did it take the 2008 version from yesterday, remains a mystey to me as well. Any suggestions??